# BeautifulSoup printing pagination along with names

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Link: https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=restaurants&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA

I am scraping names from yelp.com but it also print the page numbers below. How can I target only the names using BeautifulSoup? I am sharing couple screenshots. How can I target the name attribute showing in the inspect element screenshot?

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=restaurants&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA"

yelp_r = requests.get(url)
yelp_soup = bs(yelp_r.text, "html.parser")
# print(yelp_soup.prettify())

for name in yelp_soup.find_all("a", {"class": "lemon--a__373c0__IEZFH link__373c0__1G70M link-color--inherit__373c0__3dzpk link-size--inherit__373c0__1VFlE"}):

    print(name.text)
```

[image][image]

Comment: Note that `target` attribute is empty string. extracting `name` attribute of `a` tag, instead of `text` would not help because the pagination links also have `name` attribute with value empty string.

Comment: So, how can we fix this issue. Can you add something to the code so that I can see how it works? Sorry am new to this field.
@buran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=restaurants&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA"

yelp_r = requests.get(url)
yelp_soup = bs(yelp_r.text, "html.parser")

ul = yelp_soup.find('ul', {'class':'lemon--ul__373c0__1_cxs undefined list__373c0__2G8oH'})
for li in ul.find_all('li', {'class':'lemon--li__373c0__1r9wz border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU'}):
    for a_tag in li.find_all("a", {'class':"lemon--a__373c0__IEZFH link__373c0__1G70M link-color--inherit__373c0__3dzpk link-size--inherit__373c0__1VFlE"}):
        print(a_tag.text) # get the text
        print(a_tag.get('name')) # get the name property of a tag
```

output

```
Boo Koo
Boo Koo
Fog Harbor Fish House
Fog Harbor Fish House

... some results remove

Gary Danko
Gary Danko
um.ma
um.ma
```

Note: I didn't investigate if class name is dynamic and if changes

Answer (score 0):

I will check the contents of each tag and check if there is no keyword 'Page' in it.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=restaurants&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA"

yelp_r = requests.get(url)
yelp_soup = bs(yelp_r.text, "html.parser")
#print(yelp_soup.prettify())

for name in yelp_soup.find_all("a", {"class": "lemon--a__373c0__IEZFH link__373c0__1G70M link-color--inherit__373c0__3dzpk link-size--inherit__373c0__1VFlE"}):
    if 'Page:' not in str(name.contents[0]):
        print(name.contents[0])

Result:

San Francisco, CA
Restaurants
Boo Koo
...
Palm House
Anchor Oyster Bar
```

Comment: why does it also print the "location" and the "category" with names?